# TDBChart: Not all X axis values for one series showing in bar graph when I use two independent series on the same chart

Tags: teechart

I have a DBChart with two TBarSeries attached via IDE (XE2). All settings are applied in the IDE as well, nothing done during runtime. This data is a count of records per date within a defined date range, each series having its own ADO query. Both queries counting from different tables.

If one series has data points (dates) far outside of the other, those data points outside of the other will not show on the chart. This seems to affect only the Orange series, the second series added to the chart.

In the attached images, I show the chart and the database data for the blue and orange bars.

The chart, on the left hand side you can see first data points that are shown. The dates are jumbled together some (I'm working on that) but the first date is 5/8/19. You can't scroll left.

There are orange data points before that time frame that will not show. (April and March)

I have "All Series Visible" selected in the Marks tab of the series setup.

Thank you

[Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gmGeJ.jpg)

[Blue Bar Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rgizF.jpg)

[Orange Bar Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4VLUb.jpg)

Comment: I've rolled back your edit. If you've solved the problem and want to share that solution, do so properly by writing an answer in the space below. See [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 0):

With Axis minimum and maximum set to automatic, the first and last values of the first series sets the minimum and maximum values. If any values on the second series attached to the chart are outside of the already established min and max values, they will not show on the chart.

Set automatic to false on the chart axis.

Set minimum and maximum values at run time based on min and max values between both data sets.